# Grails - Hibernate XML - Dynamic Methods

Tags: xml, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails project that is using Hibernate XML. The Hibernate file are all in conf/hibernate/[DomainName].hbm.xml and the matching source domain files are in src/groovy/[DomainName].groovy  I keep getting:

> No signature of method: static
>   com.x.domain.Role.findByAuthority() is
>   applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String)

It looks like the dynamic finders are not on the class, although I don't see why not. Any suggestions?

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.x.domain" default-lazy="false">

    <class name="Role" table="x_roles" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <comment>Role</comment>

        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native">
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="description"/>
        <property name="authority"/>

        <set name="users" table="x_user_roles" lazy="false">
            <cache usage="read-write"/>            
            <comment>User - Roles Associations</comment>
            <key column="role_id"/>
            <many-to-many column="user_id" class="com.x.domain.User"/>
        </set>
    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

Example domain:

```
package com.x.domain

/**
 * Role class for Authority.
 */
class Role {

    public static String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER"
    public static String ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN"

    String description
    String authority = 'ROLE_'

    Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String description, String authority) {
        this.description = description
        this.authority = this.authority + authority
    }


    static constraints = {
        authority(blank: false)
        description()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to account for the problem, but a rollback to earlier code fixed the problem.